# Unexpected result while iterating over a dictionary and adding the key-values to an empty dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Could someone help me to understand the code below, this is regarding dictionaries.

Why the for loop works well until I add the last line:

```py
elif student_scores[score] <= 70:
    student_grades = student_scores[score]="Failed
```

I even tried using the "else" conditional but the result is the same: `"Failed"`.

If I delete the last part, then the result is as expected:

```py
{'Harry': 'Exceeds Expectations', 'Ron': 'Acceptable', 'Hermione': 'Outstanding', 'Draco': 'Acceptable', 'Neville': 62}
```

Why it only gives me the key value of the last condition and removes everything else?

Code:

```py
    student_scores = {
      "Harry": 81,
      "Ron": 78,
      "Hermione": 99, 
      "Draco": 74,
      "Neville": 62,
    }
    student_grades = {}
    for score in student_scores:
      student_grades = student_scores  
      if student_scores[score] >= 91:
        student_grades = student_scores[score]="Outstanding"
      elif student_scores[score] >= 81:
        student_grades = student_scores[score]="Exceeds Expectations"
      elif student_scores[score] >= 71:
        student_grades = student_scores[score]="Acceptable"
      elif student_scores[score] <= 70:
        student_grades = student_scores[score]="Failed"
    
    print(student_grades)
```

Result: Failed

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your intention to create a new dictionary with the results from this comparison mapped to the values in the original?

Comment: Hello Chad, yes it is

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `student_grades =`  at the start of each line after the `if` or `elif` statements. Simply having `student_scores[score]="Outstanding"` and the like will work.

Also the iteration variable `score` is misleading. If you print it out at any time you'll see that it's the student's name and not their score.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response, I see my mistakes now and you are right, I should have used "student" instead of "score" because it is misleading.
Also, just for me to understand (I'm just starting with python), in my initial code, why it replaces everything at the end with the last line result?

Comment: Your last line does two things. Firstly it does ```student_scores[name]="Failed"``` which sets the value of dictionary student_scores as "Failed" for the key name, and returns the dictionary student_scores. It then does ```student_grades =... ``` which sets the whole dictionary student_grades to be the (now updated) dictionary student_scores.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are just getting the last value of student grades.

```
for score in student_scores:
  student_grades = student_scores  
  if student_scores[score] >= 91:
    student_grades = student_scores[score]="Outstanding"
  elif student_scores[score] >= 81:
    student_grades = student_scores[score]="Exceeds Expectations"
  elif student_scores[score] >= 71:
    student_grades = student_scores[score]="Acceptable"
  elif student_scores[score] <= 70:
    student_grades = student_scores[score]="Failed"

print(student_grades)
```

Your `print(student_grades)` is outside the for loop, so just getting the last value stored on student grades. I would recommend you make changes like this.

```
student_scores = {
"Harry": 81,
"Ron": 78,
"Hermione": 99,
"Draco": 74,
"Neville": 62,
}
student_grades = student_scores
for name, score in student_scores.items():
    # We dont need to assign student_grades each time
    if student_scores[name] >= 91:
        student_grades[name] = "Outstanding"
    elif student_scores[name] >= 81:
        student_grades[name] = "Exceeds Expectations"
    elif student_scores[name] >= 71:
        student_grades[name] = "Acceptable"
    elif student_scores[name] <= 70:
        student_grades[name] = "Failed"

for grades in student_grades.items():
    print(grades)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually replacing the scores in the student_grades dictionary with the scores. If you change the last statement to "Print student_grades" you will see this. To add items to the student_scores dictionary you must use the "append" modifier.

Change each statement after your if statements to something like:
student_grades["Name"].append["student_name"]
student_grades["Score"].append["Excceeds Expectatios"]
This will add elements to the student_grades dictionary for each student

Comment: Your final result appears to replace all the others only because it is outside the loop. Think of it as placing messages in an envelope. Each time the loop is processed, the previous message is removed and the result for the current student is placed in the envelope. Only after all the students have been processed is the message read (printed). If the print statement is inside the loop, the message (grade) will be read each time.

Comment: Python, being an interpreted language instead of compiled, gives rise to a sparse construction. White space is important. the position of the start of lines is important. Instead of a "next" statement which is typical in compiled languages, it is merely the position of the statement that is important. If you indent the "print" statement to line up with the "elif", it will be "inside" the loop